# How to get sum(1:"by_element_of_vector_y") to work

Tags: r

My problem distills to something like this not working:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
myfn <- function(z){sum(1:z)}
myfn(x)
```

I would like the function take a vector as an input and do: (sum(1:1), sum(1:2), sum(1:4), sum(1:4)) if, for example, it takes x as an input.

So the output would be (1,3,6,10).

However, I get:

```
Warning message:
In 1:z : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: See `help("cumsum")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Vectorize` to apply the custom function on vector of `length` greater than 1

```
Vectorize(myfn)(x)
```